# Django Named groups not matching

Tags: python, django, django-urls

These are my files:

*urls.py:*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from eiris_wipro.views import *   

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   (r'^hello/$',hello),
                   (r'^articles/(?P<collection>)/$', restusers),
)
```

*views.py:*
    from django.http import HttpResponse

```
def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello new world!")

def restusers(request, collection='smthn'):
    print 'Collection', collection
    return HttpResponse(collection)
```

When I try hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/smthn/`, I get `404` error!!

I should be missing something very basic. What could be that?

Comment: your urlpatterns do not include `/smthn/` but `/articles/smthn/`

Comment: @alko: oops typo. Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't given the pattern anything to capture. It should be:

```
r'^articles/(?P<collection>\w+)/$'
```

assuming you want to capture any number of alphanumeric characters.